# missing driver for smart card reader Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b9)

Tags: drivers, kernel, hardware, card-reader, ricoh

Thanks for all who could help me to install a driver for smart card reader Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b9).

The driver is available here:
[Ricoh RL5C476](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdricohcs/)

And according to http://sdricohcs.sourceforge.net/ the driver has been 
included in the official kernel sources.

Unfortunately the smart card reader Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II still not 
recognized by Ubuntu for me.

Windows XP works with it correctly.

I did not manage with installing the driver because of missing: `kernel-source` and `kernel-syms`

> 02:06.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b9)
>   
> Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30be
>   
> Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 18
>   
> Memory at e4100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>   
> Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=176
>   
> Memory window 0: 84000000-87fff000 (prefetchable)
>   
>  Memory window 1: 90000000-93fff000
>   
> I/O window 0: 00005c00-00005cff
>   
> I/O window 1: 00005800-000058ff
>   
> 16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
>   
> Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
>   
> Kernel modules: yenta_socket
>
> 02:06.1 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b9)
>   
> Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30be
>   
> Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 19
>   
> Memory at e4101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>   
> Bus: primary=02, secondary=04, subordinate=07, sec-latency=176
>   
> Memory window 0: 80000000-83fff000 (prefetchable)
>   
> Memory window 1: 8c000000-8ffff000
>   
> I/O window 0: 00005400-000054ff
>   
> I/O window 1: 00005000-000050ff
>   
> 16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
>   
> Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
>   
> Kernel modules: yenta_socket

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Ricoh RL5c476 is a multifunction (4-in-1) device and the driver you linked supports the MMC/SD part of the chip. Unfortunately, you will have no chance of getting the SC reader part to work with Linux because, as far as I know, there are no public specifications available.

The most recent source I could track is *rather* clear:

> Dear Martin,
>
> Thank you very much for the proposal.
>   However, we don't have the intention of disclosing our technical information for linux driver.
>
> Best regards,

(http://www.mail-archive.com/muscle@lists.musclecard.com/msg07782.html)

However, the software overview of some HP notebooks  (for instance, HP-Compaq 6910p) reports a generic *Certified SuSe Linux Enterprise Desktop 10*, meaning that there **could** be a non-free driver somewhere in the wild, but do not count on that.